# Get the value from a json in v-select

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

```
<v-form :model='management'>
 <v-flex xs3 sm2 md3>
  <div class="form-group>
   <v-select
    :items="days"
    item-text='text'
    item-value='text'
    placeholder="MM"
    single-line
    attach
    v-model="week.day"
    >
   </v-select>
  </div>
   <input type="text" id="day" name="day" v-model="week.day['text']"  >
 </v-flex>
 <v-btn @click.prevent='submitManagement'> Save</v-btn>
</v-form>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        days: [
          {text: '01'},
          {text: '02'},
          {text: '03'},
          {text: '04'},
          {text: '05'},
          {text: '06'},
          {text: '07'}
        ],
        week: {
          day: ''   
        }
    }
 }
</script>
```

The Issue I am facing here that the value which I select from the dropdown for the days is not entered in the input field. I am not able to figureout the reason why. Am I doing something wrong. Help me find my problem.

Comment: Why do you want an input with the same value as your select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the v-model of the input you just need `week.day` not `week.day['text']`

Comment: I have a payment method for which I need it.

Comment: Can't you use the value from the select or are you wanting users to be able to change it in the text field?

Comment: I see, ok. Has my answer helped you?